# System.TypeInitializationException SDK

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, .net-core, dji-sdk

I got a `System.TypeInitializationException` when I try to call `DJISDKManager`.

It's on the first line of my script :

`DJISDKManager.Instance.SDKRegistrationStateChanged += Instance_SDKRegistrationEvent;`

The project is in .Net Core because I need this (or the Framework but the sdk seems to be not compatible)

Any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

which DJI SDK you are using? You try to use DJI Android SDK with .Net core?

Comment: No the windows SDK